# Control distribution of docker swarm services across different computers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Is there a way to control the distribution of services across different computers? I have one master with two workers and 5 services:

- web server
- database
- redis
- celery
- s3 storage connection

I only want to outsource the celery workers and run everything else on the master. Is there a way to control that with `docker swarm`? I have not created a registry yet, because I am not sure if that is still necessary.

Here is my current **experimental** docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.8"
 
volumes:
  s3data:
    driver: local

services:
  web:
    image: localhost:5000/web
    build: .
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=develop
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
      - ./lib/lrg_omics/:/lrg-omics/
      - s3data:/datalake/
      - /data/media/:/appmedia/
      - /data/static/:/static/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - s3vol
    links:
      - redis:redis
    restart: always
  
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - /data/db/:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  celery:
    restart: on-failure
    image: pp-celery-worker
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "celery -A main worker -l info --concurrency 8"
    env_file:
      - ./.env    
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
      - ./lib/lrg_omics/:/lrg-omics/
      - s3data:/datalake/      
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - web
      - s3vol
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        max_replicas_per_node: 1


  s3vol:
    image: elementar/s3-volume
    command: /data s3://PQC
    environment:
      - BACKUP_INTERVAL=2
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
      - ENDPOINT_URL=https://example.com
    volumes:
      - s3data:/data
```

When I deploy this with `sudo docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-distributed.yml QC`

And then look at the services I get something like this:

```
sudo docker stack services QC
>>>
ID             NAME        MODE         REPLICAS               IMAGE                        PORTS
xx5hkbswipoz   QC_celery   replicated   0/2 (max 1 per node)   celery-worker:latest         
natb3trv9ngi   QC_db       replicated   0/1                    postgres:latest              
1bxpkb18ojay   QC_redis    replicated   1/1                    redis:alpine                 *:6379->6379/tcp
6rsl5gfpd0oa   QC_s3vol    replicated   1/1                    elementar/s3-volume:latest   
aszkle6msmqr   QC_web      replicated   0/1                    localhost:5000/web:latest    *:8000->8000/tcp
```

For some reason only `redis` and the `S3` containers run. And both of them on the master. Nothing runs on the workers.

I am quite new to `docker swarm` so there is probably more than one thing wrong here. Any comments on best practices are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

To determine why the services are not starting
`docker service ps QC_celery --no-trunc` will show the state of the service and a message from docker.

To control placement consult the [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#placement) on placement constraints. Basically it entails adding to the `deploy:` node:

```yaml
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        max_replicas_per_node: 1
        constraints:
        - node.role==worker
```

While, nominally, compose.yml and stack.yml files share a format, they support different feature subsets and for complex deployments it becomes helpful to split the deployment into discreet compose.yml files for docker compose and stack.yml files for swarm deployments.

`docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml -c docker-stack.yml QC` can merge a docker-compose.yml base file with stack specific settings, and you can keep docker compose artifacts in your `docker-compose.override.yml`. these artifacts include:

`build:` - docker swarm needs the image to be built and available in a registry, either local(swarm hosted?) or docker-hub.

`depends_on:`, `links:` - not supported by swarm, which assumes services can be restarted at any time, and will find each other using docker networks.

`restart:` controlled by `restart_policy:` under `deploy:`

Comment: Thank you for sharing!!